# Why isn't there a CanTell trait/interface in Akka?

Tags: akka

ActorRef has these methods:

```
 final def tell(msg: Any, sender: ActorRef): Unit 
 def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit
```

ActorSelection has these methods:

```
 def tell(msg: Any, sender: ActorRef): Unit  
 def !(msg: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit
```

Is there a reason these methods are not part of a CanTell trait or something like that? I recently changed some code to send messages to an ActorSelection instead of an ActorRef. I thought it would be nice if I could write my code more generically to accept anything that I can send messages to.

I got this from the snapshot documentation but it looks like it is the same in the 2.2.3 api.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is not a answer to your question directly but you could use one of the scala features where you define accepted types by methods that is has, e.g.:

```
def foo(a : {def length : Int}) { a.length}
```

If such a trait will be created you won't have to change much of your code, but to be honest this looks pretty ugly to me :)

Comment: Note that structural types are implemented via reflection and are slower than other types.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using implicit conversions.

```
trait CanTell {
  def tell: (Any, ActorRef) => Unit  
  def ! : (Any) => Unit
}

class CanTellRef(ref: ActorRef) extends CanTell {
  def tell = ref.tell _
  def ! = ref ! _
}

class CanTellSelection(ref: ActorSelection) extends CanTell {
  def tell = ref.tell _
  def ! = ref ! _
}

object CanTell {
  implicit def actorRef2CanTell(ref: ActorRef) = new CanTellRef(ref)
  implicit def actorSelection2CanTell(ref: ActorSelection) = new CanTellSelection(ref)
}

def doIt(actor: CanTell) = {
  actor ! DoSomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that in the Akka Typed APIs (which deprecate `ActorSelection` in favor of messages to a receptionist actor), `ActorRef`, `EntityRef` (in cluster sharding), and `TestProbe` (from the test kit) all extend `RecipientRef` which is effectively the `CanTell` interface (the ask pattern is also provided by these interfaces).